# This redundant Readonly prefix

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

```
internal abstract class ReadonlyCoefs
{
    public const Boolean Allowed = true;
    public const Boolean Disallowed = false;

    public abstract Boolean GetCoef();
}

internal class Coefs : ReadonlyCoefs
{
    public override Boolean GetCoef()  { ... }
    public void SetCoef()  { ... }
}
```

Now, suppose i want to use it somewhere like this

```
if (variable == ReadonlyCoefs.Allowed)
    ...
```

I don't think i want to have Readonly prefix.

In this case i can just add instance methods IsAllowed and SetAllowed, SetDisallowed, but if there are a lot of consts, how to be in such a case?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here, or how you are using this. Can you provide some more code that explains how you would use this, and exactly what it is you feel you need to improve?

Comment: You are writing bad code, public constants are evil.  Use *enum* instead.  Probably solves your dilemma as well, whatever it might be.

Comment: @HansPassant I can't use enum with Boolean.

Comment: Stop using Boolean, the GetCoef() method return type should be the *enum* type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you want, at least for now. In C# 6, there will be the ability to import the static members of a class with the `using` directive:

```
using static SomeNamespace.ReadonlyCoefs;
```

That would allow access to the static members of `ReadonlyCoefs` without specifying the type name.

That said, given your current design I agree with Hans that you should be using `enum`:

```
enum CoefPermission
{
    Allowed,
    Disallowed,
}

internal abstract class ReadonlyCoefs
{
    public abstract CoefPermission GetCoef();
}
```

Then:

```
if (variable == CoefPermission.Allowed) ...
```

That should also be compatible with the `using static` feature in C# 6. I.e. you could have `using static SomeNamespace.CoefPermission;` and then the code could read `if (variable == Allowed) ...`.

Now, all *that* said, I'm skeptical of your current design. Maybe it makes sense for non-`bool` values (especially if you switch to an `enum`-based approach). But you didn't show anything like that. All you've got are `bool` values, and IMHO making constants *or* enums for those would be silly. Instead, why not just have something like:

```
internal abstract class ReadonlyCoefs
{
    public abstract Boolean IsCoefAllowed();
}

internal class Coefs : ReadonlyCoefs
{
    public override Boolean IsCoefAllowed()  { ... }
    public void SetIsCoefAllowed()  { ... }
}
```

Then:

```
if (variable) ...
```

Even better if you give the variable a good name:

```
if (isCoefAllowed) ...
```

IMHO, that's a lot more readable and maintainable.